# FancyBox 3 fullscreen image

Tags: css, fancybox, fullscreen

I'm using `fancybox3` and I would like on click of an image to start the `fancybox` with 100% `width` and `height` of the screen.
I used this `css` to have the images in fullscreen

```css
img {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.fancybox-slide img {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

but it changed the way `fancybox` works.
Instead of starting the zoom transitions from the image, enlarge and start playing, the first image starts coming from the upper left corner.

Is there a way to keep the effects and use 100% `width` and `height` of the window?